# objective-c. How to work with immutable Dictionary and return a copy?

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, functional-programming, immutability

I'm new in objective-c

The idea is that I'm passing a Dictionary to a method that return an altered Dictionary back.

I have a human "breath" method that expects as argument "air" Dictionary and returns another "air" dictionary.

test

```
-(void)testBreathIsConsumingTheRightAmountOfOxygen {
    NSDictionary *oldAir = [[Environment alloc] init].air;
    NSDictionary *newAir = [self.hummy breath:oldAir];
    XCTAssertEqual([[newAir valueForKey:@"O2"] intValue], 995);
}

-(void)testBreathIsProducingTheRightAmountOfDioxide {
    NSDictionary *oldAir = [[Environment alloc] init].air;
    NSDictionary *newAir = [self.hummy breath:oldAir];
    XCTAssertEqual([[newAir valueForKey:@"CO2"] intValue], 5);
}
```

code (my pour solution, I don't like it)

```
- (NSDictionary *) breath: (NSDictionary *) air {
    int breathingStep = 5;
    int oxygenOut = [[air valueForKey:@"O2"] intValue] - breathingStep;
    int dyoxideOut = [[air valueForKey:@"CO2"] intValue] + breathingStep;

    NSMutableDictionary *newAir = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:air];
    [newAir setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:oxygenOut] forKey:@"O2"];
    [newAir setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:dyoxideOut] forKey:@"CO2"];

    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: newAir];
}
```

The *air Dictionary looks like this

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNumber numberWithInt:1000], @"O2", [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"CO2", nil ]
```

Comment: A side-note: The designated method of `NSDictionary` to get an object value for a given key is `objectForKey:`. Use the KVC method `valueFroKey:` only if your really need it.

Comment: You tagged this question [tag:functional-programming]. Was this intentional? A functional approach would use a [(confluently) persistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure#Confluently_persistent) representation of a dictionary.

Comment: Yes it was, I'm looking for a solution that would satisfy that requirement too.

Answer (score 2):

As a side note you should really be using the modern Objective-C syntax when dealing with `NSDictionary` and `NSNumber`.

I think you're looking for the `mutableCopy` method which returns a mutable version of the current dictionary.

```
- (NSDictionary *)breath:(NSDictionary *)air {
    int breathingStep = 5;

    NSMutableDictionary *newAir = [air mutableCopy];
    newAir[@"O2"] = @([air[@"O2"] intValue] - breathingStep);
    newAir[@"CO2"] = @([air[@"CO2"] intValue] + breathingStep);

    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:newAir];
}
```

To make this better the keys (`O2` and `CO2`) should be constant, for example:

```
NSString *const kBreathO2Key = @"O2";
NSString *const kBreathCO2Key = @"CO2";
```

Usage would be:

```
newAir[kBreathO2Key] = @([air[kBreathO2Key] intValue] - breathingStep);
```

To make this even better again it may be more appropriate to create a class to hold these values rather than a dictionary. Then you wouldn't need to convert between `NSNumber` and `int`.

```
@interface ASAir : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger O2;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger CO2;

@end

@implementation
@end
```

Then the `breath:` method could be improved as follows:

```
- (ASAir *)breath:(ASAir *)air {
    int breathingStep = 5;

    ASAir *newAir = [[ASAir alloc] init];
    newAir.O2 = air.O2 - breathingStep;
    newAir.CO2 = air.CO2 + breathingStep;

    return newAir;
}
```

Comment: Yeah using a custom class is the way forward and moving the `breath` into that class is an even better idea (passing it `breathingStep`; whatever that is).

Comment: I agree with using a class for the real world implementation. I'm just using this case to understand how to use immutable dictionaries. Ideally in a functional way.

Thank you so much for your answer, I learned a lot.